# How to workwith generators from file for tokenization rather than materializing a list of strings?

Tags: python, string, list, split, generator

I have 2 files:

**hyp.txt**

```
It is a guide to action which ensures that the military always obeys the commands of the party
he read the book because he was interested in world history
```

**ref.txt**

```
It is a guide to action that ensures that the military will forever heed Party commands
he was interested in world history because he read the book
```

And I have a function that does some calculations to compare the lines of the text, e.g. line 1 of hyp.txt with line 1 of ref.txt.

```
def scorer(list_of_tokenized_hyp, list_of_tokenized_ref):
   """
   :type list_of_tokenized_hyp: iter(iter(str))
   :type list_of_tokenized_ref: iter(iter(str))
   """   
   for hypline, refline in zip(list_of_tokenized_hyp, list_of_tokenized_ref):
       # do something with the iter(str)
   return score
```

And this function cannot be changed. I can however manipulate what i feed to the function. So currently I'm feeding the file into the function like this:

```
with open('hyp.txt', 'r') as hypfin, open('ref.txt', 'r') as reffin:
    hyp = [line.split() for line in hypfin]
    ref = [line.split() for line in reffin]
    scorer(hypfin, reffin)
```

But by doing so I have loaded the whole file and the split string into memory before feeding it into the `scorer()`.

Know that the `scorer()` is processing the files line by line, is there a way not to materialize the split string before feeding into the function **without changing the `scorer()` function**?

**Is there a way to feed in some sort of generator instead?**

I've tried this:

```
with open('hyp.txt', 'r') as hypfin, open('ref1.txt', 'r') as ref1fin, open('ref2.txt', 'r') as ref2fin:
    hyp = (h.split() for h in hypline)
    ref = (r.split() for r in hypline)
    scorer(hypfin, reffin)
```

but I'm not sure whether the `h.split()` has been materialized. **If it has been materialized, why? If not, why?**

If I could change the `scorer()` function, then I could easily add this line after the `for`:

```
def scorer(list_of_tokenized_hyp, list_of_tokenized_ref):
   for hypline, refline in zip(list_of_tokenized_hyp, list_of_tokenized_ref):
       hypline = hypline.split()
       refline = refline.split()
       # do something with the iter(str)
   return score
```

But this is not possible in my case, since I can't change that function.

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or Python 3?  In Python 2, `zip` returns a list, so the call to `zip` in `scorer` will make a list even if you try to be clever before calling `scorer`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your generator expressions combined with Python 3's `zip()` (replace with `itertools.izip()` in Python 2) behave as you require, i.e. they do not read the entire file to create the splitted lists in one go.

You can get some idea as to what is going on by substituting a logging version of `str.split()`:

```
def my_split(s):
    print('my_split(): {!r}'.format(s))
    return s.split()

>>> hypfin = open('hyp.txt', 'r')
>>> reffin = open('ref.txt', 'r')
>>> hyp = (my_split(h) for h in hypfin)    # N.B. my_split() not called here
>>> hyp
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x7fa89ad16b40>
>>> ref = (my_split(r) for r in reffin)    # N.B. my_split() not called here
>>> ref
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x7fa89ad16bd0>

>>> z = zip(hyp, ref)    # N.B. my_split() not called here
>>> z
<zip object at 0x7fa89ad15cc8>

>>> hypline, refline = next(z)
my_split(): 'It is a guide to action which ensures that the military always obeys the commands of the party\n'
my_split(): 'It is a guide to action that ensures that the military will forever heed Party commands\n'
>>> hypline, refline = next(z)
my_split(): 'he read the book because he was interested in world history\n'
my_split(): 'he was interested in world history because he read the book\n'
>>> hypline, refline = next(z)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
```

From the output of `my_split()` you can see that `hyp` and `ref` are indeed generators that do not consume input until required. `z` is a `zip` object that also does not consume any input until accessed. The `for` loop is simulated with `next()` to demonstrate that only one line of input from each file is consumed at each iteration.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, your example defines two generators

```
with open('hyp.txt', 'r') as hypfin, open('ref1.txt', 'r') as reffin:
    hyp = (h.split() for h in hypfin)
    ref = (r.split() for r in reffin)
    scorer(hyp, ref)
```

and the `split`, and the corresponding reading of the next line, is done for each for-loop-iteration.